# iOS application negative badge number?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, badge

Is it possible to set the application icon badge on an iOS application to a negative integer? Seems that whenever I try to use -setApplicationIconBadgeNumber with a negative integer the badge icon is not being displayed at all.

We have a weather application and we would like it to present the temperature in the icon, as some other applications do it.

Comment: No way, sorry. It is impossible

Comment: any workarounds, like decrease the current badge number through a local notification?

Comment: There are no workaround for this at the current time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One weather application that I have seen displays 1005 for -5 degrees, 1010 for -10 and so on to display temperature in the app-icon badge. As other people also commented, it is not possible to display negative numbers nor zero.

Comment: Thanks. +1 for the suggestion.